# Hibernate features that aren't part of JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

Can you point out some Hibernate features that aren't part of the JPA specification? I've been searching for a while and could not find anything related to this topic.

Concrete examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadocs for the hibernate specific annotations is probably a good place to start.
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/package-summary.html